# backup .sql file is empty

Tags: php, mysql, backup

i am trying to backup mysql database by using this code

```
    include ("functions_cp/f_connection.php");

        Sqlconnection() ;



    $dbname = "Reservebox";
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "123";



$backupFile =  $dbname . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.sql';

$command = 'mysqldump -h' .  $dbhost . ' -u ' . $dbuser . '-p =' . $dbpass . ' '. $dbname . ' > ' . $backupFile ;
system($command);
```

the script works fine and it generates a .sql file , however this file is empty , how can i fix this problem ?

thanks

Comment: does it works if you `echo $command` and you run it manually?

Comment: @Book Of Zeus this is an action file , i use a form with `submit` button to create the backup

Comment: @BaderHAlRayyes, that's not important. Just to *debug* temporarily, you should echo the command to make sure it looks like what you are trying to make it look like, and to make sure it runs.

Comment: For example, just by inspecting I already spotted two things that will not make it run (see my example). It would be even easier for you to spot them if you just echo it out temporarily to see.

Comment: i did put an `echo` but nothing happened , no sign for errors or anythin , the file is generated but its 0KB .

Comment: @BookOfZeus yes it does work with echo and no sign for errors.

Comment: @BaderHAlRayyes can you try to use a path like: `/tmp/` and see if it's working?

Comment: @BookOfZeus i did it like this `' . '/backup/'. $backupFile ;` but the backup folder is empty and no file.

Comment: @BaderHAlRayyes does your user that runs the script have the permission to write to that folder?

Comment: @BookOfZeus if you refer to the windows user , yes .

Comment: @BookOfZeus ok , now i removed on slash from `/backup/` and it generates a file to the folder but its 0KB again :( .

Comment: what the output of the php command shows?

Comment: @BookOfZeus nothing , it just gives me a white page.

Comment: if you check the processses running, do you see the the mysqldump running?

Comment: @BookOfZeus no it doesn't , however i tested the line on the `CMD` Command line and it worked perfectly , i got a file with 22KB how strange is that !

Answer (score 1):

Don't put a space or equals sign between the `-p` and the password. Also, you are missing a space before the `-p`.

```
$command = 'mysqldump -h' .  $dbhost . ' -u ' . $dbuser . ' -p' . $dbpass . ' '. $dbname . ' > ' . $backupFile ;
```

Comment: i removed the spaces and the `=` , it was a typo , but nothing happened , still the same issue.

Comment: Then please do what @Book Of Zeus said and echo the command to make sure the rest looks right.

Comment: @BaderHAlRayyes, also I just edited my post to fix a mistake. You can't have the "=" sign either. Try it now.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a file permissions error.  Check that whatever user PHP and MySQL are running as have the permissions to write the file.  FOr troubleshooting purposes, chmod the directory to 0777 and see if that fixes the problem.  If so, chown the directory to whatever user MySQL is running as.

Comment: how can i chmod a folder to 0777 in my local machine ?

Comment: Windows has a feature similar to chmod, but 99.99% of the time it is not a problem on a windows machine.  For your situation I highly doubt that's the problem.  Sorry

Comment: i got all permissions on the folder

Comment: well, thats not the problem then.  If you are getting a blank file try echoing the command and making sure the syntax is correct.  thats all i can think of